# A weird Timinig issue with "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" in OpenCL

Tags: profiling, opencl

I'm new to opencl and I'm experiencing a weird issue with it! I have a reduction kernel and I repeat it several times! The problem is that when I profile the execution of kernel the elapsed time (queued->end) is almost same and a bit increasing but when I measure the elasped time within "C++" code the time for the execution of line "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" increases with a rapid rate!! I have attached both the code and the output of profiling! :shock:

```
// execute the kernel
globalWorkSize[0] = this->reduction_NumBlocks * this->reduction_NumThreads;
localWorkSize[0] = this->reduction_NumThreads;

//Start Time
ttt.start();

clErrNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQueue, kernelReduction, 1, 0,
globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, &timing_event);
// check if kernel execution generated an error
oclCheckError(clErrNum, CL_SUCCESS);

clFinish(clCommandQueue);
ttt.stop();

//Check Elapsed Time
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED,
sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
cout<<"ElapseTime(Execute):"<<(time_end - time_start)/1000<<"us\tTTT:"    <<ttt.getElapsedTimeInMicroSec()<<endl;
```

and this is the output:

```
    GeForce GTX 550 Ti
    Device Timer Resolution:1000ns
    GpuExecutionTime:160us   C++ElapsedTime:177
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:167
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:166
    GpuExecutionTime:189us   C++ElapsedTime:242
    GpuExecutionTime:158us   C++ElapsedTime:215
    ...
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:253
    GpuExecutionTime:162us   C++ElapsedTime:261
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:262
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:254
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:254
    GpuExecutionTime:160us   C++ElapsedTime:261
    GpuExecutionTime:167us   C++ElapsedTime:279
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:264
    ...
    GpuExecutionTime:159us   C++ElapsedTime:263
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:261
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:260
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:263
    GpuExecutionTime:264us   C++ElapsedTime:384
    ...
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:304
    GpuExecutionTime:161us   C++ElapsedTime:314
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:308
    GpuExecutionTime:160us   C++ElapsedTime:305
    GpuExecutionTime:158us   C++ElapsedTime:311
    GpuExecutionTime:156us   C++ElapsedTime:308
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:312
    ...
    GpuExecutionTime:157us   C++ElapsedTime:326
    GpuExecutionTime:158us   C++ElapsedTime:326
    GpuExecutionTime:159us   C++ElapsedTime:330
    GpuExecutionTime:158us   C++ElapsedTime:328
    GpuExecutionTime:158us   C++ElapsedTime:335
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

P.S. The size of input and other related vairables are fixed!

Comment: I am not sure how did you start your timer from CPU side, ttt.stop and ttt.start is ttt an instance of System.Timers class ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: No!! I use gettimeofday() funtion in linux!
the timer is accurate and after a while a feel the decrease in the speed myself!!

Comment: Since I don't have the full code (kernel+host) I can't comment much, but try running this under one of the profiling tools either Vtune from Intel or CodeAnalyst from AMD, find out whether your fn/observation tally's with the Profiling tool

Comment: If the time does not increase to infinity I wouldn't care. That timing function has not microseconds precision. And can fluctuate depending on many things. Stick to the profiling value is a better choise.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue (extended in https://github.com/ganyc717/Darknet-On-OpenCL/issues/4). Did you find any solution?