# Darknet - OpenCL weird continous increment of time in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

Tags: opencl, yolo, darknet

I am facing an issue with OpenCL version of Darknet. I digged into  the implementation and realized that the problem is in the call of a softmax kernel (which happens in https://github.com/ganyc717/Darknet-On-OpenCL/blob/c13fefc66a13da5805986937fccd486b2b313c24/darknet_cl/src/blas_kernels_cl.cpp#L1020). I reported it in an issue on github (https://github.com/ganyc717/Darknet-On-OpenCL/issues/4). But meanwhile I am trying to understand what could be happening.
[image]

I profiled the time that the algorithm takes to perform the prediction and it increases over runs. Just for curiousness, I decided to reload all the network before each run and then the time spent in the prediction of the algorithm remains stable, thus it seems, to me, that it is something that depends on the continuous execution of the algorithm.

What is weird to me, is that what it seems to get slower over time is the call to the kernel,i.e. the call to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. I am not an expert in OpenCL, but it does not seems logical that executing the kernel several times gets slower. Could it be a memory issue? How can it affect to the execution time? I am a bit lost, any help is appreciated.

PD: a similar issue was reported in [A weird Timinig issue with "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707357/a-weird-timinig-issue-with-clenqueuendrangekernel-in-opencl#) but not answer is marked. It has a comment related to the way of measuring the time, but I think it is not my case because the time is obviously growing.

**EDIT**: 
I modified the code to enable CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE. Then  I added the following lines to profile the enqueue call:

```
    cl_ulong time_start;
    cl_ulong time_end;

    clGetEventProfilingInfo(e, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(e, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);

    double nanoSeconds = time_end-time_start;
    printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %0.3f milliseconds \n",nanoSeconds / 1000000.0);
```

These measures of time remain stable... That confuses me more. It seems that the GPU run it self takes the same time, but when the measure of the  cpu call it grows in time:

```
clock_t t1 = clock();
cl_event e;
cl_int status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(*cl->queue, kernel, 3, NULL, global_size, NULL, NULL, NULL, &e);
clock_t t2 = clock();
printf("enqueue : \t %f\n",(float)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```